# .Net core, use of <Select> in function not working

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, html-helper

In .cshtml page, I have created the following method

```
@functions
{
    public string GenerateSelect()
    {
        <select>
            <option value="0">Ignore</option>
            <option value="-1"></option>
        </select>

        return "";
    }
}
```

Tried to use like

```
<td class="borderLeft">
   @GenerateSelect()
</td>
```

but the code doesn't even compile and giving error

**Error**
*Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MVC1006 The method contains a TagHelper and therefore must be async and return a Task. For instance, usage of ~/ typically results in a TagHelper and requires an async Task returning parent method.*

If we use other simple html tag then the GenerateSelect() method works fine, like

```
  public string GenerateSelect()
   {
       <div>
           hello
       </div>

       return "";
   }
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Note that returning `string` was irrelevant. Since you weren't using the result, it should have been `void`. Called from a C# block  `@{ GenerateSelect(); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your select option's contains value which will be regard as the html taghelper. So you should use   `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` instead of string as in your function method.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
@functions
{
    async System.Threading.Tasks.Task GenerateSelect()
    {
        <select>
            <option value="0">Ignore</option>
            <option value="-1"></option>
        </select>
    }
}

@{await GenerateSelect();}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try making it async as it suggests?

```
@functions
{
    public Task GenerateSelect()
    {
        <select>
            <option value="0">Ignore</option>
            <option value="-1"></option>
        </select>
    }
}
```

Comment: It gives error
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0161 '_Views_Template_Mapping.GenerateSelect()': not all code paths return a value

Comment: @GurpreetKailey Actually I think you need to use helpers, see docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/ui-layouts-and-themes/creating-and-using-a-helper-in-an-aspnet-web-pages-site#creating-a-helper